# OpenLDAP Centos 7 "no certificate" when client query with 'id ${USER}'

Tags: linux, ldap, centos, openldap

I've setup a test LDAP server and client on Centos 7 (OpenLDAP 2.4.39).  I'm able to do a ldapsearch on the client, but not able to get correct authentication when running 'id ${USER}'.  It seems something is not picking up the right TLS certificate (on the client?) as the server log says "no certificate" when 'id' command is issued on client.  Below is the command outputs and  /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and /etc/nsswitch.conf.  What am I missing?

Client  is able to do a ldapsearch correctly with a user dn:

```
# ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com -D "uid=nssproxy,ou=users,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com" -W  -d -1
...
tls_read: want=48, got=48
0000:  98 6b 1f 36 29 b7 2a 95  c9 88 5f 9b a5 d3 04 2e   .k.6).*..._.....
0010:  3c 04 02 a1 b6 49 1a 40  fc ad 7e ba 62 c4 db 48   <....I.@..~.b..H
0020:  16 48 31 92 6e 8d fb f8  09 8d 47 06 5d 7f 1d 67   .H1.n.....G.]..g
TLS certificate verification: subject: CN=ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com, issuer: CN=CAcert,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=com, cipher: AES-128, security level: high, secret key bits: 128, total key bits: 128, cache hits: 0, cache\
misses: 0, cache not reusable: 0
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
...
```

Results returned:

```
dn: uid=nssproxy,ou=users,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
uidNumber: 1003
gidNumber: 1002
userPassword:: MTIzNDU=
cn: nssproxy
sn: nssproxy
homeDirectory: /home/nssproxy
uid: nssproxy
```

Server log when client run the 'id ${USER}' command:

```
TLS certificate verification: subject: no certificate, issuer: no certificate, cipher: AES-128, security level: high, secret key bits: 128, total key bits: 128, cache hits: 0, cache misses: 220, cache not reusable: 0
5534a6b6 connection_read(19): unable to get TLS client DN, error=49 id=1219
5534a6b6 conn=1219 fd=19 TLS established tls_ssf=128 ssf=128
5534a6b6 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
5534a6b6 daemon: activity on:5534a6b6
5534a6b6 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
```

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf on client machine:

```
# cat sssd.conf

[sssd]
services = nss, pam, autofs
config_file_version = 2
domains = default

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home
filter_users = root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,newsnsdc

[domain/default]
# comment out ldap_tls_reqcert also doesn't work
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
autofs_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = #
ldap_search_base = dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/certs/cacert.pem
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_bind_dn = uid=nssproxy,ou=users,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com
ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com

ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = 12345
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf on client:

```
# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
hosts:      files dns

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss
netgroup:   files sss
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the problem was.  Needed to put a ldap_default_bind_dn on client as server has prohibited anonymous bind.